# Create a command shortcut for NERDTree in Vim editor

Tags: vim, command-line, command, nerdtree

I'd like to create an abbreviation for NERDTree on the command-line. I find it annoying have to write `:NERDTree` every time I want to enable it. So I'd like to type `:nr` or something like that. Is that possible?

Comment: Note: Vim doesn't let you add custom commands that start with a lowercase. For Instance, ':ne' would not be valid, but ':Ne' would be.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

In my `.vimrc` I have:

```
let mapleader = ","
nmap <leader>ne :NERDTree<cr>
```

So when I need NERDTree I just write `,ne` in normal mode.

Comment: If you want do it like in your question, then add to `.vimrc`: `:command NE NERDTree`. Than you can call it: `:NE`

Comment: Thanks! I've been using ```nmap <leader>ne :NERDTreeToggle<cr>``` to toggle NERDTree on and off.

Comment: Why isn't this a default =(

Comment: It would be nice is this focused in NERDtree if it was already open.

Comment: @jamapag if you have no object, you should make this `:NERDTreeFocus` so it doesn't open multiple copies.

Answer (score 31):

I find this works very nicely, better than any other suggestions I've tried:

```
map <silent> <C-n> :NERDTreeFocus<CR>
```

You just hit control-n to go back to the hierarchy.  Selecting a file name in the hierarchy will switch you, of course, to that file.

1. It works in both normal and insert mode
2. It doesn't close the hierarchy as the accepted answer does (using the `:NERDTree` command starts you from scratch, closing the hierarchy, while using `:NERDTreeFocus` simply moves the focus, which I think is what you want)

Comment: For me in INSERT mode Control-N was always code completion. And it stil is with this mapping.

Answer (score 24):

To toggle, use the following:

`map <silent> <C-n> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>`

Comment: this solution is very practical

Answer (score 6):

For ex Sublime users:

```
map <silent> <C-k>b :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

add to your rc file (.bashrc / .zshrc) this shortcut

```
alias nerd="nvim -c \"NERDTree\""
```

then, reload your bash width

```
source ~/.zshrc # or ~/.bashrc according your case
```

and run

```
nerd
```

---

the **-c** flag allows you to execute a command when starting the terminal

```
nvim -c "command"
```

Answer (score 0):

.vimrc:

```
let mapleader = "n" #nerdtree  
nmap <leader> :NERDTreeFocus<cr>
let mapleader = "f" #focus
nmap <leader> :NERDTreeToggle<cr>
```

.bash_profile:

```
alias n="vim -c 'NERDTree'"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).